# Is it possible to retrieve the data directory path via the REST API?

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

I'm writing a client for the GeoServer REST API and I want to create a data store for a directory of shapefiles. Since the REST API does not offer this functionality (only stand-alone shapefiles can be uploaded), I want to provide the functionality in my own client.

To do that, I need to know the path to the data directory, which is determined by [`GeoServerResourceLoader.lookupGeoServerDataDirectory(...)`](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/0054d601f5283fbde087bb253286e9512185d998/src/platform/src/main/java/org/geoserver/platform/GeoServerResourceLoader.java#L574). I've looked at the documentation and source code, and it doesn't seem to be exposed by the REST API. Have I missed something or is it indeed not possible to retrieve the path?

Comment: You could add the ability to upload directories to geoserver too

Comment: @iant my knowledge of Java is limited to reading it, I'm mainly a C# developer. But I'll take it into consideration.

Comment: @iant isn't there a REST API for resources already? It may be allowing uploads already, but I'm not sure: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/resources.html

Comment: @AndreaAime that does seem to be a viable alternative. I've only tested GET requests for now, but it seems to allow full access to the data directory. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe it's available, but adding a Spring MVC controller (on master) to also have it should not be hard, see the contribution rules here:
https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

If you need also to backport on the stable series, then you'll have to rewrite it using Restlet (GeoServer switched library this winter at the beginning of the 2.12.x development period).

Comment: Thanks for the info. (As I replied to @iant) my knowledge of Java is limited to reading it, I'm mainly a C# developer. But I'll take it into consideration.